# Document Viewer Defaulting to Inverted Colors

Tags: display, evince

Recently, when I use Document Viewer (Evince 3.18.2) to look at a PDF (especially one
I made by printing to a file), it comes out in inverted color mode (white type on 
a black background).

I can change the mode by doing this: View -> Inverted Colors

Then I get a normal display.

I do not know how the Document Viewer got into this mode, but I'd like to get it
back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what happened. Apparently, I had been displaying inverted colors and I inadvertently clicked "Save Current Settings as Default".

Comment: thanks, this help me figure out how to keep the inverted color mode on